# Сделать цикл с перебором из переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть две переменной.
Первая `i=31;` 
Вторая `i2='2 4 5 8 9';` 
Как вывести цифры от 1 до 31, но без цифр указанных во второй переменной?

есть календарь надо всем классам day-number(цифра) добавить класс `number`
кроме тех что указаны в `i2='2 4 5 8 9';`

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">
<tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day-head">Пн</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Вт</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Ср</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Чт</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Пт</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Сб</td>
<td class="calendar-day-head">Вс</td>
</tr><tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>
<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>
<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>
<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number1">1</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number2">2</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number3">3</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number4">4</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number5">5</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number6">6</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number7">7</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number8">8</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number9">9</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number10">10</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number11">11</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number12">12</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number13">13</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number14">14</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number15">15</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number16">16</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number17">17</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number18">18</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number19">19</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number20">20</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number21">21</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number22">22</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number23">23</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number24">24</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calendar-row">
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number25">25</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number26">26</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number27">27</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number28">28</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number29">29</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number30">30</div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number day-number31">31</div></td>
</tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Приложите пример вашего кода- что вы пытались сделать когда решали данную задачу.

Comment: Что означает последнее предложение? Цифры и числа различаете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Вначале нужно строку преобразовать в массив,, по разделителю `" "` (`split(' ')`)
2. Затем полученный массив строк преобразовать в массив чисел (`map(v => v - 0)`)
3. А потом пробежаться циклом и проверить наличие элементов (`indexOf()`)

```js
const i = 11;
const i2 = '2 4 5 8 9';
const skip = i2.split(' ').map(v => v - 0);
for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  if (skip.indexOf(j) === -1)
    console.log(j);
}
```